# How to validate number in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin

I am learning Django,looked into django validation but the below type i want.searched in google no result.

In my app,their are two character fields,i want it to be validate so that the conditons are,

1.Either any one of the field is entered.

2.It should validate the entered data are integer.

that means,both fields are not mandatory,but any one is mandatory and that mandatory field should accept number only.

How to do it in django.

Comment: you can validate it in the forms' clean methods

Comment: so,how to validate for blank space as per my above case

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    field_one = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    field_two = forms.IntegerField(required=False)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        field_one = cleaned_data.get('field_one')
        field_two = cleaned_data.get('field_two')

        if not any([field_one, field_two]):
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'Please enter a value')

        return cleaned_data
```

- Using an IntegerField will validate that only numeric characters are
  present, covering your blank space use case.
- Specifying `required=False` on both fields allows either field to be left blank.
- Implementing `clean()` on the form gets you access to both fields.
- `.get()` will return `None` if the key isn't found, so the use of
  `any([field_one, field_two])` will return true if at least one of the
  values in the list isn't `None`. If neither value is found, the
  `ValidationError` will be raised.

Hope that helps you out.